# Self reference rails in a ternary relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am building a social site in which a member can invite another member to an event here is picture to how the ERD looks like

[image: https://41.media.tumblr.com/14f889d005b1df1c123500a0de133cb6/tumblr_nr3m0dUgIL1r3syg3o1_400.png]

how would I set up the relation in the migrations and model? The rails documentation handles binary relations.

Comment: Only members who have an invite can attend the event correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By providing the class_names, and foreign_keys to your `has_many` relations, you can name your associations whatever you want. The `Invitation` model will serve as the join, to link your Events to the Members that have invited each other.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :invites, class_name: "Invitation", foreign_key: "invited_member_id"
   has_many :invitees, class_name: "Invitation", foreign_key: "inviting_member_id"
end

class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :event
   belongs_to :inviting_member, class_name: "Member"
   belongs_to :invited_member, class_name: "Member" 
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :invitations
    has_many :invited_members, through: :invitations
    has_many :inviting_members, through: :invitations
end
```

can be used this way..

```
?> m1 = Member.find 1
=> #<Member id: 1, username: "user1", created_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:41", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:41">
>> m2 = Member.find 2
=> #<Member id: 2, username: "user2", created_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:43", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:43">
>> e = Event.create name: "my cool event"
=> #<Event id: 2, name: "my cool event", created_at: "2015-07-07 04:11:49", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:11:49">
>> Invitation.create event: e, inviting_member: m, invited_member: m2
=> #<Invitation id: 2, event_id: 2, inviting_member_id: 1, invited_member_id: 2, created_at: "2015-07-07 04:12:01", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:12:01">
>> m1.reload
=> #<Member id: 1, username: "user1", created_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:41", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:41">
>> m1.invites
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
>> m1.invitees
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Invitation id: 1, event_id: 1, inviting_member_id: 1, invited_member_id: 2, created_at: "2015-07-07 04:03:58", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:03:58">, #<Invitation id: 2, event_id: 2, inviting_member_id: 1, invited_member_id: 2, created_at: "2015-07-07 04:12:01", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:12:01">]>

>> e = Event.first
=> #<Event id: 1, name: "Cool", created_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:54", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:54">

>> e.inviting_members
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Member id: 1, username: "user1", created_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:41", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:41">]>
>> e.invited_members
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Member id: 2, username: "user2", created_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:43", updated_at: "2015-07-07 04:01:43">]>
```

Invitations Migration:

```
class CreateInvitations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :invitations do |t|
      t.references :event, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :inviting_member_id
      t.integer :invited_member_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to change the primary keys of the invitation table?

Comment: i don't see why.  The invitation basically stands alone. my code above is just very bare minimum to show how to create the associations.  I am gong to assume that would have other fields, such as accepted_on, declined_on, etc.  and could then build scopes/associations for those.  Invitation will have its own primary key,. and just contains references to the other tables (you should created indexes and foreign keys as required)

Answer (score 0):

The member/invite/event relation can be generally though as the following:

**models**

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :invites
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :members, :through :invites
end

class Invite < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :member
end
```

This modeling show us that a member has many invites where each of those invites belong to a specific event. Now, you want to have access to all the members (the ones who received an invite) of a particular event; this is accomplished by using the `has_many` `:through` association.

Hope this helps